# Creating Pie Subplots of Circular Type in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a pie subplot in a plot using a DF. But all my pie charts are not actual circular but the first two are coming as ellipse.Please guide me how to make all the subplots of same size and circular.
Codes that I am using is given below

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(131)
ax2 = plt.subplot(132)
ax3 = plt.subplot(133)

ax1 = test1_pie.plot(kind='pie',y=test1,ax =ax1)
plt.axis('equal')

ax2 = test2_pie.plot(kind='pie',y=test2,ax=ax2)
plt.axis('equal')

ax3 = test3_pie.plot(kind='pie',y=test3,ax=ax3)
plt.axis('equal')
```

Comment: try with the `pie` function as well. also post a complete code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Azad, tagging with the specific plot type is probably creating more noise than it actually helps. As a rule of thumb I would only add tags of which you could imagine people are actually selecting for.

Comment: @cel ok you're right

Comment: @MoChen, you may want to give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to mix state-machine `pyplot` calls and normal axes method calls.  This is a classic example of why.

`plt.<whatever>` will refer to the *last axes created* in this case.  You're only calling `axis('equal')` on the last axes object.

It's best to stick to the normal axes-method api instead.

For example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(131)
ax2 = plt.subplot(132)
ax3 = plt.subplot(133)

ax1 = test1_pie.plot(kind='pie', y=test1, ax=ax1)
ax1.axis('equal')

ax2 = test2_pie.plot(kind='pie', y=test2, ax=ax2)
ax2.axis('equal')

ax3 = test3_pie.plot(kind='pie', y=test3, ax=ax3)
ax3.axis('equal')
```

As a stand-alone example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

for ax in axes:
    x = np.random.random(np.random.randint(3, 6))
    ax.pie(x)
    ax.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]